# How do you fin and update objects in a document's array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've been desperate for a few days now that I'm looking for a way to update an object that is inside an array
Here is a short excerpt from my code

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62684e70e89eca781cc4f384"
  },
  "user": "ronen",
  "roles": {
    "User": 2001,
    "Editor": 1984,
    "Admin": 5150
  },
  "password": "$2b$10$pO52RJD0zgFHDW6BBCo5iu3A5Lx0TCbCbzgjvc3FxxQZGUjblSPaK",
  "Stock": [
    {
      "sku": "777",
      "productname": "rone4n",
      "sendout": 5,
      "recived": 3,
      "totalinstock": 55,
      "location": "A770770",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "626a9bb384cd350c6e784794"
      }
    },
    {
      "sku": "ex77xee",
      "productname": "ron",
      "sendout": 43,
      "recived": 34,
      "totalinstock": 444,
      "location": "fff",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "626adab728fcc6005453a481"
      }
    }
  ],
 
}
```

I want to return the only where "sku": "ex77xee"
icant undersdet how to search object in array

```
{
      "sku": "ex77xee",
      "productname": "ron",
      "sendout": 43,
      "recived": 34,
      "totalinstock": 444,
      "location": "fff",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "626adab728fcc6005453a481"
      }
```

I prefer to do this on the MongoDB side,
i try with findONe but i unsuccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this query, You can read more about [$elemMatch here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
db.collection.find({
  stock: {
    $elemMatch: {
      sku: "ex77xee"
    }
  }
},
{
  "stock.$": 1,
  "user": 1, //<-- You can remove this, if you don't want these values
  "roles": 1, //<-- You can remove this, if you don't want these values
  "password": 1 //<-- You can remove this, if you don't want these values
})
```

You can check [mongo playground here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-_BxDu1zlOg)

`$elemMatch` is very versatile, you can add more conditions to filter later on if needed